# Banner halt on tap and hover

Tags: jquery, banner

I need to halt my banner on my desktop and mobile version, for this in my `jquery-main.js` my snippet is like below:

```
jQuery('desktop-version-class, mobile-version-class').scrollAbsoluteGallery({
pauseOnHover: true,
});
```

But sometimes its working and sometimes not in desktop version, whereas in mobile version when I tap on screen it stops but after swipe the banner it does not stop even on tap.

Comment: Is `scrollAbsoluteGallery` some kind of plugin or your custom function?

Comment: Thanku @justinas for your reply, yes this is a function

Comment: plugin jQuery Cycle Carousel plugin

Comment: What does your function do than?